# How to create tree structure in Jasper Report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I  need to display a hierarchical data structure in a report.

Something like this

[image: Sample Table]

My data structure is:

```
class X
{
    List<Y> list;
}

class Y
{
   List<Z> list
}
```

How is this achieved in jasper report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieving that kind of layout with the datastructure you have showed is normally done by using subreport (or list / table component)

**The structure would be:**

1. Main report, iterate on all `x` include a `subreport 1` for `y` and `z` passing the `List<Y> list` as datasource.
2. Subreport 1, iterate on all `y` include a `subreport 2` for `z` passing the `List<Z> list` as datasource.
3. Subreport 2, iterate on all `z`.

To generate the datasource the [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) can serve you well example `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{list})`

To achieve that **rowspan** use the `stretchType` attribute on `reportElement` (RelativeToBandHeight or RelativeToTallestObject)

Example

```
<textField>
    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="bf6b550c-f37d-4e10-b8dd-1d91c4e6905a"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
        <font size="12"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{x}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

You don't like subreports, for one level structure the `<jr:list>` component can be used, see [samples](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/list/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue, after searching for a while,  we decided to resolved it by using jasper-report html component. What it does is, it allows us to add html content in report. So, we generated html content and stored it in database. and inserted the html data in jasper report. Hope this helps.

Comment: The HTML component works for as long as your content does not need to break across multiple pages. If you ignore pagination and always target HTML export, you should be fine. But as soon as we talk about PDF or other page oriented formats, the HTML component starts to show its teeth. We actually created that component to demonstrate its limitations in these situations.